# Bloquear fechas vencidas en un input type date

Tags: html, html5, validación

Como puedo bloquear fechas anteriores en un input type date

Comment: ¿puedes explicar un poco mas?, no se entiende bien que intentas lograr.

Comment: en un formulario de reservas, necesito desactivar las fechas pasadas. que solo se pueda seleccionar la fecha desde hoy hacia adelante.

Answer (score 7):

Utiliza el atributo `min`:

```
<input type="date" min="2016-01-01">
```

Aquí tienes algo de documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Answer (score 5):

En `HTML5` existe el atributo `min`, desafortunadamente `HTML5` no tiene ninguna forma de sacar la fecha actual para poderla poner como  `value` de un atributo.

Posibles soluciones:

PHP:

```
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" placeholder="Introduce una fecha" required min=<?php $hoy=date("Y-m-d"); echo $hoy;?> />
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('#fecha').value = new Date().toDateInputValue();
```

Javascript con ayuda de jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#fecha').val(new Date().toDateInputValue());
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo quieres validar del lado del servidor (PHP) utiliza lo siguiente:

```
    $fechaEntrada = '2016-07-22';
    $fechaLimite = '2016-08-01';
//si la fecha enviada del form es menor a la que deseas validar
        if( strtotime($fecha_entrada) < strtotime($fecha_limite) ) {
        //la fecha es menor
        }else{
        //la operación fue realizada en un periodo válido
        }
```

Para validarlo en JS puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var fechaEntrada = '2016-07-22';
var fechaLimite = '2016-08-01';
if( (new Date(fechaEntrada).getTime() < new Date(fechaLimite).getTime()))
{
   //alert('la fecha es menor'); 
    //return false;
}else{
 //return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuve la misma duda, pero utilizando java script puedes resolverlo de mandera sencilla

Primero recuerda que debes tener habilitado el atributo min en tu input

`<input type="date" id="fechaReserva" min="2017-01-01" />`

Luego utiliza esta funcion reemplazando obiamente los id

```
    var fecha = new Date();
    var anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    var dia = fecha.getDate();
    var _mes = fecha.getMonth();//viene con valores de 0 al 11
    _mes = _mes + 1;//ahora lo tienes de 1 al 12
    if (_mes < 10)//ahora le agregas un 0 para el formato date
    { var mes = "0" + _mes;}
    else
    { var mes = _mes.toString;}
    document.getElementById("fechaReserva").min = anio+'-'+mes+'-'+dia;
```