# Colocar límite de días en un input day

Tags: html, angular

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario con un input type date en el cuál como valor mínino se encuentra el día actual al que se accede, quiero agregar un límite de 2 días o 48 horas al input.

```
<input class="inputDate" type="date" [(ngModel)]="fecha" min="{{todate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

Ese es el input que uso y la variable todate se encuentra en el archivo .ts y la cual tiene como valor new Date;

```
todate = new Date();
```

Como puedo sumar los dos días o las 48 horas a la etiqueta input.

Saludos

Comment: Prueba creando una variable y sumando dos días a la fecha actual -> `fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + 2);` y esa variable la especificas en el html

Comment: Gracias @PauloUrbanoRivera no se me habia ocurrido

Comment: Ten en cuenta que sólo estas específicando como mínimo y máximo el día, no la fecha completa!

Comment: eso ya lo corregí seteando el formato de fecha que deseo

Answer (score 0):

lo que intentas es limitar los dias anteriores al de hoy podrias usar el atributo min de HTML5:

```html
<input type="date" min="2016-01-01">
```

[Aqui tienes la documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

[Fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18289/bloquear-fechas-vencidas-en-un-input-type-date)